# Java parsing XML: getElementsByTagName returns all elements

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, nodelist

I have the following xml structure:

```
<node name="node1">
    <parameter name="param1" value="1" />
    <parameter name="param2" value="2" />
    <parameter name="param3" value="3" />

    <option name="opt1">
        <parameter name="opt1-p1" value="11" />
        <parameter name="opt1-p2" value="12"/>
        <parameter name="opt1-p3" value="13"/>
    </option>
</node>
...
```

The file contains several nodeElements with several options.

Using the statement getElementsByTagName

```
       ...
       Node nNode = nodeListSessions.item(nodeIndex);
       Element nodeElements = (Element) nNode;
       NodeList nodeListParameters = nodeElements .getElementsByTagName("parameter");
       ...
```

It gets all the parameters including the parameters from the option inner-elements.

How can I receive in a nodelist (nodeListParameters) only the parameters of node element?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a simple [XPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) expression: `/node/parameter`.

This will only get **parameter** elements within root-level **node** elements. You can use the XPath classes provided in `java.xml.xpath` like so:

```
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/node/parameter");

NodeList nodeListParameters = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

You'll need to have your XML `doc` as some kind of [`InputSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) object, such as an [`org.w3c.dom.Document`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java) for more details.

You can play around and test different xpath queries [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/34c1f082a3a124b98b78049ff68559d1).

Comment: I t works but I would like to not use xpath, just the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that i found was to check the parent node if it is "option" or "node"
e.g

```
if ((element.getNodeName() == "parameter") & (element.getParentNode().getNodeName()== "node")) {
... }

if ((element.getNodeName() == "parameter") & (element.getParentNode().getNodeName()== "option")) {
... }
```